# UISearchController takes the wrong item

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code here I touch on + before search It gives correct product. but the problem is  after search, it gives previous product not the correct product[image: my table view]

after searching UISearchController looks up self.tableView
search is working finely

[image]

table view

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    // Configure the cell...
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "MasterViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MasterViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of OutletViewCell.")
    }

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.

    var product = products[indexPath.row]
    if isFiltering {
        product = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        product = products[indexPath.row]
    }



    cell.productName.text = product.productDescription
    cell.availQty.text = "Avail. Qty:" + String(product.stock)
    cell.productPrice.text = "Price: " + String(product.defaultSellPrice)
    cell.addItem.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addItem.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    orderDetails.forEach { detail in
        //   print(word.price)
        if detail.key == product.id {
            cell.AddedQty.text = "Qty :" + String(detail.value.qty)
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

here is buttonTapped function

```
    @objc func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    // print("Button pressed " + String(button.tag))
    let product=products[button.tag]
    print(product.productDescription)
    showAlert(product: product)

}
```

Comment: you also need to check if the data isFiltered or not on button tap

Comment: Use filteredProducts if isFiltering is enabled. That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your buttonTapped function, you also need to check if the data isFiltered or not

```
  @objc func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    let productData = isFiltering ? filteredProducts[indexPath.row] : products[indexPath.row]
    showAlert(product: productData)
}
```